# Tycho: How do I deploy sources jars of packaging eclipse-plugin?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3, tycho

In my parent pom I got this configuration to deploy sources jars:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
            <goal>test-jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

But the tycho build modules ignore that, so their sources aren't installed/deployed in the maven repository. Which means I can't include them in an assembly (especially if the assembly module is located in another git repository).

**Is it possible to configure one of the tycho plugins to build and deploy sources jars?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-osgi-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>plugin-source</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>plugin-source</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

See https://github.com/jsievers/tycho-demo/blob/master/tychodemo.parent/pom.xml

Comment: The groupId/artificatId should be org.eclipse.tycho and tycho-source-plugin now (since Tycho 0.12 I believe)