# Tycho: How do I deploy sources jars optional?

Tags: maven, maven-3, tycho

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702701/tycho-how-do-i-deploy-sources-jars-of-packaging-eclipse-plugin) i use this code to ship the source of my project.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>plugin-source</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>plugin-source</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

So far this works fine. I got a **xxxx.jar** and a **xxxx.source.jar**

But what if I want to ship the source optional?

Is there a way to make it possible to ship the source only on demand? Like the normal User gets it without source and an other Developer gets it with?

**EDIT**

after looking into the tycho-soure-feature-plugin this is what i get as result:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho.extras:tycho-source-feature-plugin:1.0.0:source-feature (source-feature) on project projectname.feature: Execution source-feature of goal org.eclipse.tycho.extras:tycho-source-feature-plugin:1.0.0:source-feature failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.eclipse.tycho.extras:tycho-source-feature-plugin:1.0.0:source-feature: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/tycho/packaging/LicenseFeatureHelper : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

so i looked up why there is an error -> i use JDK 1.6 and on the build server there is no other JDK installed so i cant use this plugin even if i would use Maven Toolchain

[Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135558/tycho-help-room)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s what I would do (and what I think is best practice): **Always** build the `.source.jar` of your `eclipse-plugin`s, **but** offer two `eclipse-feature`s: One which includes the source (to be installed by developers) and one which does not (to be installed by normal users). You can use the [`tycho-source-feature-plugin`](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs-extras/tycho-source-feature-plugin/plugin-info.html) for this.

Comment: can i use the source-feature-plugin even when compileSource says 1.6?

Comment: Why do you think that the `tycho-source-feature-plugin` cares which (Java) version your sources are in? The plug-in merely generates a `.source` feature containing the `.source` bundles previously generated by the `tycho-source-plugin`.

Comment: okay i misunderstood there for a bit. But the problem is still there, cause the build process goes with a ibm jdk (which is based on jdk 1.6) so this plugin won't work i think

Comment: Are you aware of [toolchains](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html)? This way, you can run your `mvn` process with a different JDK than the one you use for, e.g., [compiling with Tycho](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Execution_Environments#Toolchains).

Comment: I'm new to maven so i have to look into it. if you have some time you can join the chat room i created and linked in the question

Answer (score 0):

First of all i want to say that the answer form Andreas Sewe is right and i marked it as accepted, because if you use JDK 1.7 this is the best solution.

For my problem (only JDK 1.6 available) I solved it the way to create a new project named `xxxx.source`

That way i got a separate `xxxx.source.jar`